# Formatting MongoDB aggregation for Highcharts Stacked Columns

Tags: mongodb, highcharts, aggregation-framework

I'm attempting to plot a highcharts **stacked column chart** displaying multiple button counts per table category. For this I've built the following aggregation in mongodb:

```
var pipeline = [ 
      { 
        $group: {
          _id: {tableId: "$tableId", buttonId: "$buttonId"},
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ];
```

This gives me a JSON object with the following hierarchy:

```
0:
   count: 5
   _id:
      buttonId: "buttonId1"
      tableId: "Table1"
```

I'm trying to bring this into a format suited for highcharts, something along these lines:

```
        var buttonPerTable = [{
                name: 'buttonId1',
                data: [5, 3, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'buttonId2',
                data: [2, 2, 3]
            }, {
                name: 'buttonId3',
                data: [3, 4, 4]
            }]
    var tableList = ["Table1","Table2","Table3"]
```

This is what I've tried, but I can't quite figure out how to do it right, I can't manage to get the data into the wished format:

```
var activityPerTable = [];
var tableList = [];    
result.forEach(function(call, i) {
                buttonId = call._id.buttonId
                activityPerTable[buttonId] = []
                activityPerTable[buttonId].data = []
                activityPerTable[buttonId].name = buttonId;
                activityPerTable[buttonId].data.push(call.count);
                tableList.push(call._id.tableId);
            });

            tableList = Utils.uniqueArray(tableList);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here is a chunk of JSON object:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table1",
      "buttonId": "buttonId1"
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table2",
      "buttonId": "buttonId3"
    },
    "count": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table2",
      "buttonId": "buttonId1"
    },
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table1",
      "buttonId": "buttonId2"
    },
    "count": 8
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table1",
      "buttonId": "buttonId2"
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table3",
      "buttonId": "buttonId1"
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "tableId": "table3",
      "buttonId": "buttonId2"
    },
    "count": 6
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Cos, Please provide me with the larger part of your JSON object.

Comment: Hi ppozaczek, please see the edit. However I have the possibility to modify the way I query the mongodb, so if the json format isn't optimal I'll happily change it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit simpler if the same names were in order side by side. However, you can convert your JSON to the format required by Highcharts in this way:

```
Highcharts.each(data, function(el) {
    if (series.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            if (series[i].name === el._id.buttonId) {
                series[i].data.push(el.count);
                i = series.length + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!series.length || i === series.length) {
        series.push({
            name: el._id.buttonId,
            data: [el.count]
        });
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tnhv8u62/

Comment: Hey, what exactly do you mean by "if the same names were in order side by side"? I could try to do that.

Comment: Hello Cos, I mean this order and function: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a7qkpoyc/